# BigDecimal Method returns vague results, why does this happen?

Tags: java, eclipse, double, java.util.scanner, bigdecimal

Code:

```
package tk.vivekpatani.www;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleCalc {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Calculator!");


    System.out.println("Enter Number 1:");
    double num1 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter Number 2:");
    double num2 = sc.nextDouble();

    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(num1);
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(num2);

    BigDecimal result = addition(bd1,bd2);

    System.out.println("Result:"+result.toString());
    }
    finally{
      sc.close();
    }

  }
  static BigDecimal addition(BigDecimal input1, BigDecimal input2){

    BigDecimal result = input1.add(input2);
    return result;

  }


}
```

Results:

```
Welcome to the Calculator!
Enter Number 1:
90
Enter Number 2:
10.2
Result:100.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
```

I'm using Eclipse IDE Mars and Java 1.8.

Comment: The answer is the opposite of vague. In fact it is overly precise.

Comment: As usual, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) explains this quite well.  Short answer:  Don't create a BigDecimal from a double.

Comment: Okay, i'll keep that in mind! I read about the float and double primitive inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the javadoc of the [`BigDecimal(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) constructor:

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. [...] When a double must be used as a source for a `BigDecimal`, [...] use the static `valueOf(double)` method.

So, always use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`, never `new BigDecimal(double)`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Number 1: ");
double num1 = sc.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Enter Number 2: ");
double num2 = sc.nextDouble();

BigDecimal bd1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(num1);
BigDecimal bd2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(num2);

System.out.println("Result: " + bd1.add(bd2));
```

*Output*

```
Enter Number 1: 90
Enter Number 2: 10.2
Result: 100.2
```

Comment: Thank You, that was informative. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The `double` can't handle `0.2` properly due to the precision it uses.

Try doing this instead to create the numbers, you need to construct the BigDecimal using the Strings so that you don't carry over the `double` precision issue.

```
    System.out.println("Enter Number 1:");
    String num1 = sc.nextLine();
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(num1);

    System.out.println("Enter Number 2:");
    String num2 = sc.nextLine();
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(num2);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank You.